# sass add an extra space after compiled

Tags: sass

This is my Sass file:

```
$iconValue: '6a9';
.icon-home::before{
    content: '\e#{$iconValue}'
}
```

After the compilation I got this CSS:

```
.icon-home::before {
  content: "\e 6a9";
}
```

How can I get rid of the extra space ?

Comment: Why you are adding this #?

Comment: You could write directly `\e` in your variable: `$iconValue: '\e6a9';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations you just stumbled upon a Sass edge case in regards to interpolation ;)
To my knowledge there is not a compiler consistent way to handle this – but this fix/hack will work in most newer versions:

```
// function to wrap value in quotes (with a leading \) 
@function icon($char){
  @return unquote('"\\#{$char}"');
}


$iconValue: '6a9';
.icon-home::before{
  content: icon(e#{$iconValue});
}


//  you can also add the 'e' to the variable  
//  and make it a little more readable 
$iconValue: 'e6a9';
.icon-home::before{
  content: icon($iconValue);
}
```

Comment: This problem seems to happen only on dart-sass.
It can be tested on https://www.sassmeister.com/ which provides multiple implementations.